# display of 'sync' (mapview) in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-mapview

I’m trying to have [two spatial plots side-by-side in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139878/using-leaflet-side-by-side-plugin-in-r), and I was suggested a powerful function, `sync` of `mapview`. After figuring how to [display `mapview` object in `shiny`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270966/display-of-mapview-object-in-shiny?noredirect=1#comment67804715_40270966), I tried to integrate `sync` in 'shiny', but got the following error:  *Error in slot(x, "map") : no slot of name "map" for this object of class "shiny.tag.list"* . Does it mean `sync` does not have map object, therefore, it is not possible to integrate `sync` or `latticeView` with `shiny`? If so, I guess there should be workaround solutions and my ears are all open. This is a nice feature to have access from Shiny and allows to do some interesting things. Greatly appreciate any suggestions. Here is the sample reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(mapview)
ui <- fluidPage(
   mapviewOutput("samplemap"),
   p()
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$samplemap <- renderMapview({
      m1 <- mapview(gadmCHE,zcol="ID_1")
      m2 <- mapview(gadmCHE,zcol="OBJECTID")
      sync(m1,m2)
      })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

We have discussed making the return value from `sync` an htmlwidget.  Currently, `sync` returns a `htmltools::tagList` of the leaflet maps.  Inserting `tags` into `shiny` will be a little different than inserting `mapview`.  I'll try to explain in code below.

```
library(mapview)

m1 <- mapview(gadmCHE,zcol="ID_1")
s1 <- sync(m1,m1)


library(shiny)

# if not dynamically adding maps
#   we can just insert as ui

shinyApp(
  ui = s1,
  server = function(input,output){}
)

# if there is a need to create the maps after UI
#   then we will need to handle differently
#   since sync gives us tags instead of an htmlwidget
shinyApp(
  ui = uiOutput("syncmap"),
  server = function(input,output){
    output$syncmap = renderUI({
      s1
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Apologizes for missing the discussion part regarding `sync` returned objects. <br> This is useful, however, the map was being displayed only when `sync` object inserted as `ui`. I am unable to add maps dynamically, i.e., the code with `renderUI` and `uiOutput` opened a window but with no map. Not sure why? Also, I would like to know whether I can create a `sync` object in an reactive expression using `renderLeaflet` objects and later use in `renderUI` and `'uiOutput` ? Greatly appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: what versions of `shiny`, `htmltools`, and `htmlwidgets` do you have?

Comment: Here it is : `shiny`  _0.14.1_ `htmltools` _0.3.5_ 
`htmlwidgets` _0.7_

Comment: can you open in a browser and use F12 or CTRL+Shift+I or left-click/inspect to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Just I want to mention that it is mac, and on chrome here [is screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52kr3h17fe245cx/ErrorSyncObjectDisplay.png?dl=0) I do see at least one error, but not sure what it means.

Comment: not sure exactly, but can you try without too much hassle to do `install.packages(leaflet)` and `install.packages(mapview)` to get CRAN versions.

Comment: I'll do that, can u confirm that it is working just fine on your end ?  Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126941/discussion-between-satishr-and-timelyportfolio).